# Using which Query Implementation to get a row from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hector

I want to retrieve a row from Cassandra using column family and row key.
However when I using SliceQuery, there is an exception:Caused by: me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: Neither column names nor range were set, this is an invalid slice predicate.

Does anyone know whether I have used a wrong Query implementation?

Comment: It will probably help if you paste the relevant section of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an entire row:

```
SliceQuery query = HFactory.createSliceQuery(_keyspace, _stringSerializer, _stringSerializer, _stringSerializer);
query.setColumnFamily(columnFamily)
     .setKey(key)
     .setRange("", "", false, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```